# Deleting all files that do not match a certain pattern - Windows command line

Tags: windows, command-line

Deleting items via the command-line is pretty easy.

```
del /options filename.extension
```

Now, suppose I want to delete all files which do not end with .jpg in a folder, how would I do that.

The thing is, I have a piece of software that converts all specified images to .jpg, but it leaves the originals, which I don't need anymore.

It would be much more efficient to execute a single statement, compared to doing multiple statements for every different filetype.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
attrib +r *.jpg
del /q *
attrib -r *.jpg
```

This will first make all JPG files read-only, delete everything else (it will automatically skip read-only files), and then make the JPG files writeable again.

Comment: Worked like a champ. Note: just add `/s` to each line to recursively include files in subdirectories.

Answer (score 9):

That's actually pretty easy.

You'll need `for` to iterate over the files and then simply look for the extension:

```
for %f in (*) do if not %~xf==.jpg del "%f"
```

should do the trick (code [here](http://svn.freebsd.lando.cc/joey/Public/SO/SU32500/del_non_jpegs.cmd)).

Comment: thanks, but that alone depends on which map I'm using.

Comment: Map?

Comment: How do I say if not .jpg and not .jsp and not .xml then del ?

Answer (score 2):

Powershell to the rescue
<sup>In times of Windows 7/8 it's the successor of the good old command line</sup>

```
Del C:\myFolder\* -exclude '*.jpg'
```

`Del` is an alias for [`Remove-Item`](http://ss64.com/ps/remove-item.html). It has several options like recurse, include, exclude and filter (use this for RegEx)

You have to add `\*` to include files in a given folder

Comment: From the CMD prompt, this should work: `PowerShell.exe -Command "&{Remove-Item C:\MyFolder\* -Exclude '*.jpg'}"`

Comment: Note: PowerShell comes with Win 7/8. For Windows XP or Vista, you need to download and install it.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not answering your question directly, but have you looked at the options on your converter to see if:

1. It can delete the originals itself

*or*

2. Write the .jpg's to a new folder?

Comment: I doesn't have the direct option to do so. What it will do is overwrite the original if that was a JPG to begin with. But all others remain on the disk while a JPG of them is created.

Comment: @WebDevHobo - oh well, I'd go with Johannes suggestion then.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a way to find all files that did NOT have the extension ".mp3" in a directory TREE on Windows 7 (NTFS volume) containing perhaps 20,000 files in several hundred directories of various depths...  so after a bit of angst, I used:

```
cd <theplace>
dir /S | find /V "<DIR>" | find /V "Total" | find /V "bytes" | find /V "Directory" | find /V "Volume" | find /V ".mp3" | more /S
```

this listed the files that did not match the .mp3 after stripping out everything related to the DIR command output...  99% works...  unless the file that doesn't match is named one of the keywords in the standard DIR output - perhaps there's a way to make DIR report less header/summary info - but I didn't bother as this got most of the way there.

Comment: apparently the Posting code here strips some special characters...  so the "cd" command above was on a line by itself and specified the target root directory, and the first "find" command removed any lines that contained "<"  DIR  ">"  (go figure) since that's the output of the dir command - but the post code here may think that's some sort of meta-instruction and strips it...

Comment: There is a much easier way to do this: the `/b` flag of the `dir` command. `dir /b` will list filenames and extensions in the current directory only, `dir /s /b` will list the fully qualified names of all files in the current and all subdirectories. Piping to `find /v` instead of a `for` loop is a nice touch I'll have to remember, but I don't think it works with `del`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to delete all files matching a filename is shown below. The for loop list's all files and the if NOT matches by filename (without directory name).

```
for /r %f in (*) do if not %~nxf == abc.xml del "%f"
```