# Delete files that don't have special character ® in name or path

Tags: windows-7, windows, powershell, batch, regex

I have seen [How to delete all files that don't have a certain string in their name](https://superuser.com/questions/1053400/how-to-delete-all-files-that-dont-have-a-certain-string-in-their-name)

However, I would like to delete files that do not have a certain string in their filename **or path** (not only filename), and I would like that string to be the character ®.

Based on [this revision history](https://superuser.com/posts/1053540/revisions), the following works for the string "MS", but not for special characters:

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%i in (`dir /a:-d /b /s *.zip ^| findstr /v MS` ) do (
  echo del /s /q %%i
)
endlocal
```

Comment: For Pete’s sake. Use powershell. It’s a one liner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# ®
$specialChar = [char]0x00AE
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse | Where-Object {!$_.FullName.Contains($specialChar)} | Remove-Item
```

For older versions of PowerShell that does not support the `-File` parameter, use:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object {!$_.FullName.Contains($specialChar) -and -not $_.PSIsContainer} | Remove-Item
```

Comment: I get `Get-ChildItem : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'File'.`

Comment: @root What version of PowerShell are you on? $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Comment: version 2.0.-1.-1

Comment: @root update your powershell. Download the latest version of Windows management framework for your version of Windows.

Comment: @root - add a test for `-not $_.PSIsContainer` to the `Where-Object` scriptblock. that works for ps2 ... [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey What exactly would the entire line then look like?

Comment: @root See my updated answer.

Comment: @root - the W-O scriptblock can have more than one test - just like any IF test. so you simply add an `-and` plus the next test. just like what `FastEthernet` put in the last code line of his updated answer. [*grin*]

Comment: The script should descend recursively into subdirectories. (Note that the question had `dir /s` and that it's about the *path*, not only the file name, otherwise it would be trivial: Search for `*®*.*` in explorer, move found files elsewhere, delete remaining files.) I added `-Recurse` to the answer, waiting for peer review of the edit.

Comment: @root Edits shouldn't be made to add parameters missing from a command in another user's answer... such input would be appropriate as a comment, but not as an edit.

Comment: `Get-ChildItem` should also have the argument `-Exclude *®*` (or whatever the syntax for the special character is), otherwise it will be slow due to unnecessarily descending into directories that contain `®` in the name.

Answer (score 1):

---

> • **Update** - Using **`Powershell`**:

---

```bat
Get-childitem -re . | Where-Object {$_ -NotMatch '(?:®)'}|remove-item -recurse -force -Confirm:$false

# Or, by using alias #
gci -re . | ? {$_ -NotMatch '(?:®)'}| rd -re -force -Confirm:$false
```

---

---

> • There also, can be more short **cmd/bat**:
>
> ---

```bat
:: in command line :: 
chcp 1252 >nul & for /f "tokens=*" %i in ('dir /a:-d /b /s *.zip ^|find /v "®"')do echo=del /q /f "%~fi"

:: in cmd/bat file ::
@echo off && >nul chcp 1252

for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /a:-d /b /s *.zip ^|find /v "®"')do echo=del /q /f "%%~fi"
```

> - My previous answer with whose probable use is doubtful, but work too!:
>
>   ---

---

```bat
@echo off & >nul chcp 1252 

for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /a:-d /b /s *.zip')do (
    echo/"%%~i"|find "®">nul||echo=del /q /f "%%~fi" )
```

> Or in commandline ::

```bat
>nul chcp 1252 && for /f "tokens=*" %i in ('dir /a:-d /b /s *.zip')do @echo="%~fi"|find "®">nul||@echo=del /q /f "%~fi"
```

Obs.: To add **<kbd>®</kbd>** in your code, try...

> - Press and holding the  <kbd>alt</kbd>  (left) + (num pad) <kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>6</kbd> <kbd>9</kbd>

---

[image]

---

Maybe this can help?

---

In fact the special console character, where it activates the page and encodes it used to write / read the file name, and moves that information to variables, read and compare it all in alphabet soup, is a bit difficult to handle in cmd/bat, which is why I asked for help for a language...

Therefore, for a paranoid proposal, considering actions for delete files, I took C# to try implemented a comparison using base64 for string (wildcard alt 169 = ®).

---

> - **Obs.:** **`169 = ®`** and differs from the **`0169 = ©`**

---

The resulted from these actions, is a script cmd/bat, that at run time compiles the one C# sources into a executable, that will be used by script, to get string from file name, whether the character name is present (in base64) in the name.

---

Is this my friend, **or**, is something completely different from exposed above, and, that my English limited prevent me to explain to you clearly :)

---

> - The **`script cmd/bat`**:
>
>   ---

```bat
@echo off && setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion & chcp 1252 1>nul

cd /d "%~dp0" && set "_.net=%windir%\Microsoft.NET" && title >nul && title Q1500545 
set "_arg=/t:exe /out:"%temp%\b64.exe" "%temp%\b64.cs" /platform:anycpu /unsafe+ /w:0 /o"
set "_here=." type nul >"%temp%\b64.cs" && set "_b64=%temp%\b64.exe" && >"%temp%\b64.cs"^
   (
    echo/ using System^;namespace b64 ^{class Program ^{static void Main^(string[] args^)
    echo/ ^{if ^(args.Length ^> 1 ^&^& args[0] ^=^= "-e" ^| args[0] ^=^= "-E"^)
    echo/ ^{byte[] plainTextBytes ^= System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes^(args[1]^)^;
    echo/ Console.Write^(System.Convert.ToBase64String^(plainTextBytes^)^)^;
    echo/ ^}else if ^(args.Length ^> 1 ^&^& args[0] ^=^= "-d" ^| args[0] ^=^= "-D"^)
    echo/ ^{byte[] base64EncodedBytes ^= System.Convert.FromBase64String^(args[1]^)^;
    echo/ Console.Write^(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString^(base64EncodedBytes^)^)^;
    echo/ ^}^}^}^} 
    ) 

for /f delims^=^ eol^=* %%i in ('%__APPDIR__%where.exe /r "!_.net!" "csc.exe"^|findstr /li k\v2\.
')do "%%~i" !_arg! /nologo && cd /d "%~dp0" && goto :^?

:^?
for /f delims^=^ eol^=* %%i in ('%__APPDIR__%where.exe /r "." "*.zip"')do call :^[ %%~fi
(for %%D in (exe,cs)do del /q "%temp%\b64.%%D") & endlocal && exit /b 

:^[
for /f tokens^=* %%a in ('"cmd /u /c echo=%~1|find /v """
')do "!_b64!" -e %%~a|findstr "wq4=" >nul && exit /b )
echo/del /f /q "%~1" && exit /b
```

> - My **directory tree** for test in **`G:\SUPER_USER\Q1500545`**:
>
>   ---

```bat
G:.
¦   Q1500545.cmd
¦
+---Sub_Dir_01
¦       test_º.zip
¦       test_¿.zip
¦       test_®.zip
¦
+---Sub_Dir_02
¦       test_®.zip
¦       test_º.zip
¦       test_¿.zip
¦
+---Sub_Dir_03
¦       test_®.zip
¦       test_º.zip
¦       test_¿.zip
¦
+---Sub_Dir_04_®
        test_®.zip
        test_º.zip
        test_¿.zip
```

---

> - My **script results** by **`echo/del /f /q "%~1"`**:
>
>   ---

```bat
del /f /q "G:\SUPER_USER\Q1500545\Sub_Dir_01\test_º.zip"
del /f /q "G:\SUPER_USER\Q1500545\Sub_Dir_01\test_¿.zip"
del /f /q "G:\SUPER_USER\Q1500545\Sub_Dir_02\test_º.zip"
del /f /q "G:\SUPER_USER\Q1500545\Sub_Dir_02\test_¿.zip"
del /f /q "G:\SUPER_USER\Q1500545\Sub_Dir_03\test_º.zip"
del /f /q "G:\SUPER_USER\Q1500545\Sub_Dir_03\test_¿.zip"
```

---

> - My **`C#`** code:
>
>   ---

```bat
using System;
namespace b64 

{  
   class Program 
   {  
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         if (args.Length > 1 && args[0] == "-e" | args[0] == "-E")
         {  
            byte[] plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(args[1]);
            Console.Write(System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes));

         }  
           else if (args.Length > 1 && args[0] == "-d" | args[0] == "-D")
         {  
             byte[] base64EncodedBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(args[1]);
             Console.Write(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(base64EncodedBytes));
         }
      }
   }
}
```

---

> - My command line used to compile code **`C#`**:
>
>   ---

```bat
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\csc.exe /t:exe /out:"%Temp%\b64.exe" "%Temp%\b64.cs" /platform:anycpu /unsafe+ /w:0 /o
```

---

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

Comment: What is `\M\S`? shouldn't the entire `findstr` part be removed?  What is `~fi`?

Comment: @root This is just a simple use for an escape: Literal M Literal S, it's good for the root user to know that!

Comment: @root %%~fi  Is for token the **F**ull path of file in variable loop **`%%i`**, in this case, the zip file listed by **`dir`** command.

Comment: great detailed answer +1, but IMO super complex compared to a PowerShell oneliner

Comment: Your post consists of several answers. Please [split them into separate answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25209/what-is-the-official-etiquette-on-answering-a-question-twice). We can then discuss each answer individually in the comments, upvote each answer individually, etc.

Comment: @root I think the user's here, won't like see multiple answer post by same user, if, can put one with many options so solve a question hope you understend me.

Comment: Please have a look at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25209/what-is-the-official-etiquette-on-answering-a-question-twice

Answer (score 0):

Batch is not unicode compatible so it recognizes ® as © so I just changed ® with © in the batch file but I guess changing the code page with chcp also works. Do you want to delete all files that don't have the ® in the name or only zip files? Well if it's all files just change *.zip to * in the for:

```
@echo off
Title Delete all files that don't have © in Name
setlocal EnabledelayedExpansion

Rem Specify the path to the folder here:
set Folder=%userprofile%\desktop\test

for /r %Folder% %%a in (*.zip) do (
set Character=%%a
set Character=!Character:©=!
IF "!Character!"=="%%a" del /a /f "%%a"
)
pause
```