# Delete Files Based on extension, does not contain, and age

Tags: windows, script, ms-dos

I'm using the following post with great success on deleting files by extension except those containing keep$ in the name: 
  [How to delete all files that don't have a certain string in their name](https://superuser.com/questions/1053400/how-to-delete-all-files-that-dont-have-a-certain-string-in-their-name)

However now we would like to also add a time component to it such that only files older than 30 days are deleted. Any suggestions. I've used forfiles before to do this, however, i don't understand how to incorporate it with the above logic. The previous solution without a time component and modified for our use is:

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%i in (`dir /a:-d /b /s *.sol ^| findstr /v "[\\][^\\]*keep$[^\\]*$"` ) do (echo del /s /q %%i)
endlocal
```

Comment: What version of Windows? Can you use PowerShell?

Comment: It is on Windows Server 2019 and PowerShell is an option.